# In asp.net how to disable popup message when redirecting to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to disable popup message when redirecting to another page?

i am having login page and home page and registration page.

i gave one alert message when user name and password in correct it's display

i entered wrong username and password it display message after i am postback registration page

complete my registration  after redirect my login page that time it also displayed same alert

why this ?
how to resolve ? please help to me

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("aa", 
    "<script>alert('Please Enter Correct UserName and Password');</script>");
```

i am using this.

Comment: how are you checking username and password?

Comment: do not forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 2):

It's a logical bug. You need to check whether the Username/password fields are empty or not and if empty then you have to execute you javascript code

```
if( string.isNullOrEmpty(username) 
     && string.isNullOrEmpty(password) )
  Page.RegisterStartupScript("aa", "alert('Please Enter Correct UserName and Password');");
```

Answer (score 0):

put the `Page.RegisterStartupScript` in `if` condition in *page load* of login